# "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends" ... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, curl

Steps to reproduce: run the following code (with your email/password):

```
$data = array(
  'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
  'Email'       => 'your.email@google.com',
  'Passwd'      => 'your.password',
  'service'     => 'trendspro',
  'source'      => 'company-application-1.0'
);

$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);

$headers = array(
  "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $matches[1],
  "GData-Version: 3.0",
);

$ch = curl_init("http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=MSFT&date=2011-2&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $csv = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($csv);
```

The expected output is a http stream of data, which can be stored as a .csv file on the server. But what is being outputted is an error: "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends". This is unexpected, since I am sending the authorization-string returned from the first request, with the Google Trends request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the login actually succeeding? Does `curl_error()` say anything?

Comment: @Pekka No, curl_error($ch) doesn't return anything. So I'm assuming the login is succeeding. I have seen scripts logging in in a similar way...

Comment: $matches: Array(
    [0] => Auth=DQAAAMcAAAB-FoR_TjeD0tbpRaTHtfgfF7XV3McC5b9sjT3TFRiKcOwj2m1X2zcfnYsbenI0Mzy2P5Ev3Wo1KiCBLh3daye-rk13OFycHmVXFAGQ4XsPt7FzlDSzhx6BNyfW4yw3MD_HYPjt_in18ptESR1qlQDVe-h6TUeaa1ON2Nsk9gi871sEY5TkmjXJfMK7bPPXNl82kRKBbVf7QBZLZxbADt-5pq9QqcUubMUyKLRrffJ-L5qu9gnCt8nSNQpfhd69a0xY_qhvdYm0V2wgY7P3kgvV
    [1] => (same string as [0])
)

Comment: In other words, @Pekka, I do get an auth-token returned. As I said, it works fine up until downloading the csv :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **"hl" => "nl",** to the **$data** array, since it seems to me that google.nl needs a separate login.

Comment: I changed .the ".nl" to ".com" (see topic start)...it doesn't make a difference. Thanks for the thought though...it was rather inconsistent of me :-)